# Perl: Can not compare two strings if one of them is with special chars

Tags: string, perl, if-statement, special-characters, filepath

I am new to Perl.

I am trying to check whether an existing variable `$file_path` is equal to a specific path or not in an `if` condition.

```
my $PRODPATH = '/path/to/prod';

if ( $file_path eq "$PRODPATH/specific/path/to/file" ) {
    print "File is same as earlier \n\n";
}
else {
    print "File is not same as earlier \n\n";
}
```

But the flow is not going to any of the conditions because of the special character `$` in the string which I am comparing with `$file_path`.

Are the slashes `/` in the path also creating any issues?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Perl will interpolate the variable, so `"$PRODPATH/specific/path/to/file"` becomes `"/path/to/prod/specific/path/to/file"`, and that's what will be compared to `$file_path`. The number of slashes `/` need to be the same. Maybe `$file_path` has a trailing slash, i.e. end in `file/`?

Comment: This feels like it might be an XY problem. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: "*`$PRODPATH` is an environmental variable*" - no, it's not. It's a Perl variable. Are you using strict and warnings?

Comment: Please don't make changes to your question that change the problem altogether. Your last edit seemed to be showing that you have tried using `$ENV{PRODPATH}` as I suggested, but you haven't said anything about doing so and you haven't done the additional diagnostics that I asked for. It's fine to *add* stuff to an answer, but your should never invalidate other people's comments or answers by altering your question. If you have follow-on questions as a result of the advice you have received then you should open a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the flow is not going to any of the conditions because of the special character $ in the string

That is a wrong diagnosis, and I don't understand how you got that idea. Perl variables like `$PRODPATH` are expanded within a double-quoted string, but if you set the *Perl* variable `$PRODPATH` to the same value as the environment variable has then your code should work

You can access the environment variables through Perl's `%ENV` hash, so you should remove the definition of `$PRODPATH` and write

```
if ( $file_path eq "$ENV{PRODPATH}/specific/path/to/file" ) { ... }
```

Also, you *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of every Perl program you write.

If you still have problems, then please add this to your code and show the result

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper [ $file_path, $ENV{PRODPATH} ];
```

Comment: Adding `local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;` helps in these situations.

Answer (score 0):

In double quotes, variables are interpolated (expanded).

So this works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file_path = '/path/to/prod/specific/path/to/file';
my $PRODPATH = '/path/to/prod';
if ( $file_path eq "$PRODPATH/specific/path/to/file" )
{
  print "File is same as earlier \n\n";
}
else
{
  print "File is not same as earlier \n\n";
}
```

If `$file_path` is not *literally* the same text string, then it won't though. In particular - if the path includes extra (or trailing) slashes, or it's a relative path, or it's a symbolic link - that comparison won't work.